# Call asynchronous function inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, for-loop, scope

```
var path;

for (var i = 0, c = paths.length; i < c; i++)
{
    path = paths[i];

    fs.lstat(path, function (error, stat)
    {
        console.log(path); // this outputs always the last element
    });
}
```

How can I access the `path` variable, that was passed to fs.lstat function?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a perfect reason to use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a for loop to iterate values.

```
paths.forEach(function( path ) {
  fs.lstat( path, function(err, stat) {
    console.log( path, stat );
  });
});
```

Also, you could use a closure like @Aadit suggests:

```
for (var i = 0, c = paths.length; i < c; i++)
{
  // creating an Immiedately Invoked Function Expression
  (function( path ) {
    fs.lstat(path, function (error, stat) {
      console.log(path, stat);
    });
  })( paths[i] );
  // passing paths[i] in as "path" in the closure
}
```

Comment: Be careful with .forEach if your iterable is not exclusively formed with the elements you want to use. I'd rather be use the closure option as a general rule, IMHO.

Comment: @DanibISHOP could you expand on that? Specifically, what is "not exclusively formed with the elements"?

Answer (score 11):

Classic problem. Put the contents of the for loop in another function and call it in the loop. Pass the path as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion works nicely here (especially if you have some i/o that must be executed in a synchronous manner):

```
(function outputFileStat(i) {
    var path = paths[i];

    fs.lstat(path, function(err, stat) {
         console.log(path, stat);
         i++;
         if(i < paths.length) outputFileStat(i);
    });
})(0)
```