# Recursive self-invoked function and asynchronous operations

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, winjs

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696747/call-asynchronous-function-inside-for-loop), I gathered that I could use either a `forEach` loop or a self-invoked to perform asynchronous I/O operations. I'm not sure why it isn't working for me, but the loop part of things work properly without any asynchronous function being called.

```
var fileNames = ["fileA", "fileB", "fileC", "fileD", "fileE", "fileF", "fileG", "fileH"];
var json;

(function parseFiles(i) {

    console.log(i + " " + fileNames[i]);

    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appx:///data/' + fileNames[i] + '.json');

    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).then(function (file) {
        Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (contents) {
            json[fileNames[i]] = JSON.parse(contents);

            if (i < fileNames.length) {
                parseFiles(i+1);
            } else {}
        });
    });

})(0);
```

My console output is kind of strange:

```
0 fileA
1 fileB
0 fileA
2 fileC
1 fileB
3 fileD
2 fileC
3 fileD
```

Two questions here:

1. How do I fix it so that it goes from fileA to fileH?
2. After parsing the files, do I put the code to work with the variable `json` after the self-invoked function or in the `else` loop in the `then` function of the Promise returned by `readFileAsync()`?

Comment: You are incrementing the value if `i` from within the asynchronous function, you should probably move it to the outer function and pass in the name of the file. That won't ensure the functions complete in sequence though, you'll need to make them synchronous to do that.

Comment: @RobG Obviously you are wrong. Incrementation in asynchronous call is the entire point of doing this. The code is correct, see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cS7hs/ I've replaced asynchronous calls with setTimeout. From the output it looks like this function was called twice at the same time. The error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
var fileNames = ["fileA", "fileB", "fileC", "fileD", "fileE", "fileF", "fileG", "fileH"];
var json;

(function parseFiles() {

    var name = fileNames.pop();

    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appx:///data/' + name + '.json'))
        .then(function (file) {
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file);
        }, function error(e){
            console.dir(e);
        })
        .then(function (contents) {
            json[name] = JSON.parse(contents);
        })
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Name: "+name+" Remaining array length:"+fileNames.length);

            if (fileNames.length === 0) {
                console.log('all done');
                // do whatever else here
            } else {
                parseFiles();
            }
        });
})();
```

I'm just glad that the asynchronous methods in the recursive function use the Promise interface so I don't have to write a whole bunch of recursive functions.